# How does this function work in particular?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain me how this function works? I know the ternary operator, so I understand the part, that he checks if flag is `true`, and if not then use the 2. value. But I don't understand why `flag` is a Boolean in the first place and why it switches from `true` to `false` and vice versa when `animate()` is being called...

```
flag = $texte.data('animToggle');
$texte.data('animToggle', !flag);
$texte.animate({
    'left': flag ? '-51%' : '0'
})
```

Comment: It animates the element style between 'left:0' and 'left:-51%' each time it is called

Comment: can you show the code where `$texte` is defined and the html for it's element if possible?

Comment: `But I don't understand why flag is a boolean in the first place` what else would it be? You get the current value with `flag = $texte.data('animToggle');` and then use the logical NOT (`!`) to toggle it's value here: `$texte.data('animToggle', !flag);` So if it's true (or truthy) the first time through, it'll be `false` the next time, and vice-versa.

Comment: @paul that is not my question. My question is why flag is a boolean and why it switches it state. I know of course that animate is animating the left position.

Comment: When a variable is used in a **`boolean` context** -- correct me if I am wrong -- it should be read as, **is Defined?** thereby resulting in `true`, if defined or `false`, if not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has [*truthy* and *falsy* values](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/). These are values which equate to `true` and `false` when evaluated as Boolean. This means that `true` and `false` aren't the only values which can represent true or false data.

For example, if `$texte.data('animToggle')` is equal to `0` it will be *falsy* as `0` is a *falsy* value.

#### Example 1: `1000`

`1000` is a *truthy* value, so this will output "True":

```
var flag = 1000;
console.log(flag ? "True" : "False");

> "True"
```

#### Example 2: `""`

`""` (empty string) is a *falsy* value, so this will output "False":

```
var flag = "";
console.log(flag ? "True" : "False");

> "False"
```

---

The [`!` (Logical NOT) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) converts a value to Boolean and *negates* it. `$texte.data('animToggle', !flag);` sets the `animToggle` data property of `$texte` to the opposite of what it previously was.

```
!true   // False
!1000   // False

!false  // True
!""     // True
```

Comment: So in $texte.data('animToggle') the result will be 0 and therefore false? Then what does $texte.data('animToggle', !flag) do?

Comment: @FrederikWitte: `NOT false == true`. So it would set `animToggle` to `true` for the next cycle.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you!

Comment: One more question, I will do further reading about this, but is .data something like .prototype?

Comment: @FrederikWitte `data()` is a jQuery method. Documentation for it is available here: http://api.jquery.com/data.

Comment: @James I think my question is a little too complex for the comment section. I will try to figure this out :P Thank you really much!